# bing map v7 control buttons

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

I am using bing map in my web application using api-reference7

i i have left,right,up,down buttons and i want user when click on these buttons they should behave as buttons on the control buttons.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427611.aspx

Comment: The left,right,up,down control buttons on the V7 toolbar are not trivial at all. The amount of offset from the cursor to the buttons controls the speed of the panning, and is a constant effect as long as the mouse is pressed. Do you really need this or is something more in the likes of: "click up" -> the map shifts a specified amount of pixels up ?

Comment: yes i only want up,down,right,left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var NAVIG_MAP_LEFT=1;var NAVIG_MAP_RIGHT=2;var NAVIG_MAP_TOP=3;var NAVIG_MAP_BOTTOM=4;
    var NAVIG_MAP_STEP=100;    
function navigateMap(n, step){
            var loc = bingMap.getCenter();
            var locToPx = bingMap.tryLocationToPixel(loc);
            switch(n){
            case NAVIG_MAP_LEFT: locToPx.x = locToPx.x-step; break;
            case NAVIG_MAP_RIGHT: locToPx.x = locToPx.x+step; break;
            case NAVIG_MAP_TOP: locToPx.y = locToPx.y+step; break;
            case NAVIG_MAP_BOTTOM: locToPx.y = locToPx.y-step; break;
            }
            loc = bingMap.tryPixelToLocation(locToPx);
            bingMap.setView({center: loc});
        }
```